# Github Pages / Github automated data push policy

Tags: git, github, github-pages

For the sake of convenience, I've hosted a page in https://pages.github.com/ (until it grows in complexity), at this stage of the project, I anticipated the need to update some data hosted (50kb approx.) once every 2 days approx, but I have just noticed I will have to update the data many times during the day (once every 1-2 hours). I am fully aware Github pages was not built with such purpose in mind.

I've gone through the GitHub [terms of service](https://help.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-terms-of-service), the [API limits](https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/) and the [acceptable use policy](https://help.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-acceptable-use-policies):

- The API is only intended for searches, pulls, etc. not for pushes
- Even if I want to "push", which is different, it looks like my use would be inside what they consider reasonable (at least for the API).
- There is nothing in the general terms of service that would make that use look like a breach. They don't even mention the word "push".
- The acceptable use policy establishes limits to bandwidth (which should not be a problem here).
- The acceptable use policy bans "inauthentic interactions, such as fake accounts and automated inauthentic activity". The activity would be authentic, but obviously, automated.

Would it be OK to automatically push data 12-24 times per day? Could it represent a breach?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic. It's not in the scope of SO — questions about programming and tools. It's a legal question about an external service.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question you need to ask GitHub themselves, but here are some things you should consider:

- The purpose of GitHub Pages is to host a personal website or blog or a site for your open-source project.  If the purpose of your site is something else, you should consider hosting it elsewhere.
- If you need your page to be built within a certain timeframe or have a certain SLA, then you should host it somewhere that can provide that, since GitHub Pages doesn't make any guarantees about that.
- GitHub Pages isn't intended for commercial use, such as selling a product or service to someone, although commercially sponsored open-source projects are fine.

If you meet those criteria, then things will probably be fine, but if you want to be certain, you should ask GitHub, such as on its community forums.

Comment: There're [usage limits](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#usage-limits): source repositories have a recommended limit of 1GB; sites may be no larger than 1 GB; *soft* bandwidth limit of 100GB per month; *soft* limit of 10 pushes per hour. (I replaced *builds* with *pushes* ­— **phd**).

Comment: Answering an off topic question is off topic. It is no part of Stack Overflow’s remit to interpret some web site’s usage rules.